# "Associate with [someone]" for "socialize with [someone]" in colloquial AE

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage, colloquialisms

What's the difference in AE between saying "I like to associate with new folks" and "I like to socialize with new folks"?

E.g.

> I am a positive person and I like to associate with other positive persons. [source](http://aasa.org/SchoolAdministratorArticle.aspx?id=10756)
>
> I like to socialize with new people. [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=3p8S4oyjzmUC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22i+like+to+socialize+with+new+people%22&source=bl&ots=TegePfhMBK&sig=5Bro_lzh8CS9RE7S38HBESAGKyE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=3V4bU8XtA8aGywOP0oKIDQ&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22i%20like%20to%20socialize%20with%20new%20people%22&f=false)
>
> I like to associate with people on the same term as I do in my own country. [source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=tJoBLRjxfFwC&pg=PA58&lpg=PA58&dq=%22i+like+to+associate+with+people+on+the+same%22&source=bl&ots=cGfkyiClCG&sig=QGh3llf8sfSmK8Aeg3SSKlyFWZM&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=rF0bU7HvPKqBywPoloI4&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ)
>
> I like to socialize with my dog, and I have a cat... [source](http://www.goldengreyhounds.com/stories/kzy.html)
>
> I like to associate with other people. [source](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/article/College-Student-Journal/179348418.html)

If it all means pretty much the same, is there one of these expressions that sounds more typical of AE than other English dialects?

Comment: You should probably avoid *associate*, because with no other context, *"He associates with them"* will invariably be taken to imply that *"they"* are a bad lot, and that *"he"* would be better off steering well clear of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The negative connotation is only true if "them" is left as an ambiguous (or explicitly negative) entity. "He associates with the wealthy", for instance, isn't implying that the wealthy are a bad lot.

Comment: @MrHen: Compare Google Books totals for [he associates/d with the right.../good.../etc.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+associated+with+the+right%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) to [he associated with the wrong/bad.../etc.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he+associated+with+the+wrong%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). All other things being equal, you'll find there are *far* more instances of *"associate with X"* where ***X*** has clearly negative connotations. You may feel differently, but to me that definitely "taints" this particular construction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: My point is that there are exceptions to the general rule you have (correctly) identified. Namely, this rule does not inherently override what would normally be a positive connotation (e.g., the wealthy, the intelligent). Or, to say this another way, I am identifying a common case where all other things are explicitly *not* equal. :)

Comment: @MrHen: Well, it's not like I said *"**all** associates are **bad** people"*. I just said OP should *probably* avoid the verb form because *more often than not* it's used in contexts with negative associations (which doesn't apply to, for example, *socialise*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Correct. I was adding information; not disagreeing with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific dictionary entries show that "associate" completely encompasses "socialize", so you can use them interchangeably without fear of being misunderstood:

> **socialize** — take part in social activities: to take part in social activities, or behave in a friendly way to others
>
> **associate** —
>
> 1. connect things in mind: to connect one thing with another in the mind
> 2. pass time with somebody: to spend time together with somebody
> 3. mix socially or professionally: to be involved with somebody or something in a personal or professional capacity

But "associate" and "socialize" do carry slightly different connotations due to associate's first definition. When describing someone who *associates* with a particular group of people the connotation is that they are "associated with" that group:

> I want to be associated with intelligent people. / I want to associate with intelligent people.
>
> I want to be with intelligent people. / I want to socialize with intelligent people.

This difference is subtle, but here is how it effects two of your specific examples:

> I am a positive person and I like to associate with other positive persons.

This person wants to be around and be associated with positive people.

> I like to socialize with new people.

This person likes to be with new people. You could use "associate" here and it would have the exact same meaning -- it is unlikely you could really be associated with new people.

Answer (score -1):

I think in AE the term that fits all of the examples is **hang-out**.  You can just use **hang** but that is getting into slang territory.

Comment: Wot? And "hang-out" isn't slang? (Where did that hyphen come from, btw?)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can't put the hyphen in there?  I like the hyphen in this context.  Hangout being a place, hang out (physically hand something out), hang-out being to gather or socialize.

Comment: I've certainly never seen the verb form hyphenated. Why would you "like" it? I find it hard to believe you're *used* to seeing it written like that. I never heard of anyone using *hang out* to mean ***hand** out*, either. A long time ago the noun was hyphenated - *hang-out* being a place where people would *hang out*.

Comment: @F Well I see it written both ways.  I prefer the hyphen when the words go together but I understand both.

Comment: Well I suppose in principle that's the way these things usually go - first it's two words, then they're hyphenated, and eventually they become a single word. I'm not sure the *noun* was ever two words, but it's certainly written as a single word with no hyphen very often these days. Perhaps you just happen to see more text from people who are way ahead of mainstream usage, but I must say I'm not convinced *hang-out* will become established as a credible verb, especially given just *hang* is already common in that sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have used and see it used so many times in my life I don't take it is slang.  A girl might say to me, "Let's hang-out sometime."  Very very common.  Maybe it is regional or AE.

Comment: No, it's not "regional or AE". It's a perfectly common usage, and even my 93-year-old British father is quite capable of saying to me *"Didn't you used to hang out with so-and-so?"*. But the fact that you *hear and say* it has no bearing on what I'm questioning - the hyphen in the *written* form when used as a verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am not saying that hyphenating it is correct.  It is how I have seen it used and used it though.  Do you think it is incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure the concept of "correct" really applies here. As I said, collocations often move through from *two words -> hyphenated -> single word*. If *you* often see the ***verb*** usage hyphenated, who's to say that's incorrect. All I'm saying is the ***noun*** usage is now almost always a single word rather than hyphenated (particularly in the US), but I don't recall seeing the ***verb*** usage having moved beyond the "two separate words" version for the written form.

Comment: You might be interested in comparing noun usage [in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=favorite+hangout%2Cfavorite+hang-out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfavorite%20hangout%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfavorite%20hang%20-%20out%3B%2Cc0) with the [BrE version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=favourite+hangout%2Cfavourite+hang-out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfavourite%20hangout%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfavourite%20hang%20-%20out%3B%2Cc0) (clearly distinguished by "favourite" spelling).

Comment: I would consider "I want to hang-out with my friends" incorrect because of the hyphen. My primary dialect/region is Midwest AmE.

Comment: Also, this doesn't remotely answer the question. -1.

Comment: @MrHen - well he switched the question...